# git credential.helper instead of .netrc to get go dependencies

Tags: go, nexus, go-get, git-credential-manager, go-git

To cashing [go](/questions/tagged/go) dependencies I use [nexus](/questions/tagged/nexus)(as [goproxy](/questions/tagged/goproxy)) which connect to `goproxy` servers (because `nexus` can't get dependencies directly from `GitHub`) outside of private network.

---

nexus.some.repo.com:4443/repository/go-nexus-proxy ➡️ [gonexus.dev](https://gonexus.dev)
nexus.some.repo.com:4443/repository/go-proxy ➡️ [proxy.golang.org](https://proxy.golang.org)
***...***

---

```
GOPROXY="nexus.some.repo.com:4443/repository/go-proxy,nexus.some.repo.com:4443/repository/go-nexus-proxy"
```

[image]

and I use `.netrc` file to connect to [nexus](/questions/tagged/nexus)

```
machine nexus.some.repo.com:4443 
login SOME_LOGIN 
password SOME_PASS 
protocol https
```

Could I use `git credential.helper` instead of `.netrc`❓

If *yes*  How can I config `git credential.helper`❓

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using netrc, you could simply configure the credential helper to use netrc

You can download and put in your PATH [`git-credential-netrc.perl`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc.perl)

And then:

```
git config --global credential.helper netrc
```

Comment: Could I use `osxkeychain` (Mac) or  `store` with `go get`?

Comment: @kozmo Yes, as illustrated by https://gist.github.com/katylava/47affb3a9248cbfbf179bec6a1079cd7

Comment: @kozmo Do you mean using `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain` and a go get was not enough? Don't forget it will work with your token (https://github.com/settings/tokens) and password, not your username and password.